# Fill input field without name and click div with PHP cURL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, curl

I am trying to use PHP cURL to fill and submit a form on a url, however, they are not using the regular `form` tag with a submit button. Instead they just have a div with `onclick` to submit the value entered in the `input` field that has no `name`, but does have an `id` and an `onChange` event.

You can see it in action [here](https://sfplanninggis.org/pim/?pub=true). (You can search for '5458-011' to test.)

How do I still enter a value in this `input` field and submit it via cURL?

Below is code from that url.

HTML:

```
<input onChange="mirrorSearch2()" list="addresses2"class="Header-Search-field" id="addressInputSmall" placeholder="Search by address, parcel or planning application number, or click on the map"/>
<datalist id="addresses2"></datalist>
<div onclick="runSearch(document.getElementById('addressInputSmall').value,'','addressInputSmall')" class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" id="Search-icon2"></div>
```

Javascript / jQuery:

```
//onChange
function mirrorSearch2() {
    var thenew=$('#addressInputSmall').val()
    //console.log(thenew);
    $('#addressInput').val(thenew);
}
function mirrorSearch() {
    var thenew=$('#addressInput').val()
    //console.log(thenew);
    $('#addressInputSmall').val(thenew);
}

//onClick
function runSearch(theAddress,theType,theID) {
    //Now run a second query to get the geometry, if no geometry is found then send to old PIM search functionality (e.g. PPTS non-parcel records)
    //console.log("RunSearch: "+theAddress)

    if (theID=="addressInput") {
        //console.log($('#addresses').children().length)
        if  ($('#addresses').children().length==1  ) {
            //if there is only one option and they hit enter, then get the option value rather than search for the incomplete text.
            //e.g. if they typed 1650 miss and hit enter, then send the 1650 MISSION ST from the option list.
            $("#addresses").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
            if ($( "#addresses option:first" ).val()) {
                setTimeout('throttleSubmit($( "#addresses option:first" ).val());',400)
                return
                //theAddress = $( "#addresses option:first" ).val();
            }
        }
    }
    if (theID=="addressInputSmall") {
        //console.log($('#addresses2').children().length)
        if  ($('#addresses2').children().length==1  ) {
            //if there is only one option and they hit enter, then get the option value rather than search for the incomplete text.
            //e.g. if they typed 1650 miss and hit enter, then send the 1650 MISSION ST from the option list.
            $("#addresses2").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
            if ($( "#addresses2 option:first" ).val()) {
                setTimeout('throttleSubmit($( "#addresses2 option:first" ).val());',0)
                return
                //theAddress = $( "#addresses2 option:first" ).val();
            }
        }
    }
    //setTimeout('console.log($( "#addresses2 option:first" ).val())',100)
    //console.log(theAddress)
    throttleSubmit(theAddress)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I inspected in the browser inspector and looked in the network pane, the actual request is the following:

https://sfplanninggis.org/arcgiswa/rest/services/Geocoder_V2/MapServer/0/query?where=Address+like+%275458-011%%27&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=Address,Priority&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnDistinctValues=false&resultRecordCount=15&returnExtentOnly=false&f=json

So I assume the input name you need is "where"

Comment: Thank you so much, but how do I submit it without a submit button?

Comment: My understanding is that, if you're using PHP cURL you don't need a submit button, you just mimic the frontend of their site and submit query to their endpoint which is 
https://sfplanninggis.org/arcgiswa/rest/services/Geocoder_V2/MapServer/0/query using all the fields necessary. However, I don't know you're exact use case you can provide a bit more information. Maybe you're just trying to use HTML and submit the form...

Comment: The use case is to get the resulting information generated from the search. So, simply submitting the search term to that endpoint will work? I don't need to actually have the script click the `div`?

Comment: Well if you want to trigger and submit the form using JS just do $('#Search-icon2').trigger('click'); because it has jQuery on the website and the div has an ID, but the point of using cURL is that you generate HTTP requests directly from your script and parse results without much of JavaScript usage.

Comment: The main purpose here is to access the 'Assessor Recorded Documents' link that is generated after the search is made. What would you suggest I do to be able to access that document generated after the search?

Comment: The url you provided in the answer, it returns a json without any information about that 'Assessor Recorded Documents' document link.

Comment: With regards to my previous answer I just read the help here https://sfplanninggis.org/PIM/help.html and it seems you can simple use "search" query param e.g. https://sfplanninggis.org/pim/?search=400%20Van%20Ness%20Ave To retrieve the 'Assessor Recorded Documents' you should use PHP DOM and retrieve the URL from the href attribute of the link. You can do the same with JS as well.